# Always get the error callback on jQuery.ajax (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'am having a strange error, likely it is a server-side issue. My error callback is always triggered, even when the response status is 200!

**Javascript //client**

```
function save_pomodoro(){
j.ajax({
    url: '/app/save_pomodoro',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache : false,
    success: save_pomodoro_suc,
    error:   save_pomodoro_err,
    data: {
        bar: 'foo'
    }
})
}

function save_pomodoro_suc(data){
 alert("Pomodoro Saved Succesfuly")
}

function save_pomodoro_err(data){
 show_error(data.status, data.responseText) // on success => 200, "OK"
                                            // on fail 400, "bla bla bla"
}
```

**Rails //controller**

```
def save_pomodoro

...

p = Pomodoro.new( params[:bar] )

if p.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
    format.js {   render( :json => "OK" ) }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :action => 'index' }
    format.js {   render( :json => p.errors.full_messages.to_json, :status => 400 ) }
  end
end

end
```

I have another function (ajax+server) on this same controller that have working callbacks.
This is mysterious for me, so any insights will help

**Update: Found Error:**

```
format.js {   render( :json => ["OK"] ) }
```

Apparently the string by itself isn't a valid json.

Comment: are you getting malformed json back? how does firebug look?

Comment: @Dan Heberden The response looks ok, shows no error answer. When there is error it comes in *red*

Comment: Well, RED is the 400 error typically. Load the Net tab, make your request and inspect the response - is it valid? is it json with extra text? Maybe run it through jsonlint.com to verify it?

Comment: @Dan Heberden Thanks fot the time! It was really a bad JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful way to debug this is to change the signature of your error handler from

```
function save_pomodoro_err(data)
```

to

```
function save_pomodoro_err(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

and add an alert or some such (or debug using Firebug) to get the `errorThrown` string.

which will give you access to the specific error message thrown: you can get passed to the error handler for reasons other than a failed HTTP status, such as a parse error on the JSON, or a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
j.ajax({
    url: '/app/save_pomodoro',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache : false,
    success: function() { save_pomodoro_suc() },
    error: function() { save_pomodoro_err() },
    data: {
        bar: 'foo'
    }
});
```